# Postgres RAISE NOTICE wrapper function

Tags: postgresql

I have many `RAISE NOTICE` messages that I want to manipulate (`add date()` to all of them, or filtering some of them based on their text, etc.)

Is it smart to have call a function to trigger those messages instead of calling `RAISE NOTICE` directly?
Can adding date/filtering all messages can be done without having a wrapper function?

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulating the `RAISE NOTICE` call in a function would be the only way to configure the message in a single place. But it will add another function to the call stack, which might make the context harder to read.

Perhaps you could use `RAISE LOG` and configure `log_line_prefix` to your liking.